# Как создать специализацию для метода шаблонного класса c++

Tags: c++

Имеется шаблонный класс.
Хочу специализировать метод для определенного N, при этом не переопределять другие методы.

```
template <typename T, unsigned N>
class Test
{
private:
    T data[N];

public:
    Test(T init);
    int foo();
};

template <typename T, unsigned N>
int Test<T, N>::foo()
{
    std::cout << "Default\n";
    return N;
}

template <typename T>
int Test<T, 1>::foo()
{
    std::cout << "Special implementation\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Выдает ошибку: "список аргументов шаблона должен соответствовать списку параметров". Даже при таком коде:

```
template <typename T, unsigned N>
int Test<T, 1>::foo()
{
    std::cout << "Special implementation\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Шаблоны функций не могут быть *частично* специализированы. Для шаблонов функций поддерживается только *явная* (полная) специализация. Это правило распространяется как на шаблоны обычных функций, так и на шаблоны методов классов.

Comment: А тут не шаблон функции, а нешаблонная функция шаблонного класса.

Comment: @VTT "Нешаблонные" методы шаблонного класса сами по себе являются самостоятельными шаблонами функций и ведут себя именно как таковые. Обратите вннимание на http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.class#temp.mem.func, где ясно сказано, что определение шаблона класса заодно объявляет *три шаблона функций*.

Comment: Ключевое отличие в том, что у этих функций нет собственных шаблонных аргументов. Так что тут речь идет о частичной специализации шаблонного класса, к которому относится эта функция, а не о частичной специализации шаблона функций. Собственно приведенный код вполне себе работоспособный, стоит только добавить определение частичной специализации шаблонного класса (которого оп хочет избежать).

Comment: @VTT: Это все замечательно, но не меняет дела. Для нешаблоного метода шаблонного класса может быть выполнена *явная специализация* (*без* выполнения специализации всего класса!). Такая специализация официально называется "явной специализацией функции-члена шаблонного класса" (http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.expl.spec#1.4). Сделать аналогичным образом *частичную* специализацию функции-члена шаблонного класса невозможно - такого возможности в языке нет.

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить использовать `if constexpr`:

```
template <typename T, unsigned N>
class Test
{
private:
    T data[N];

public:
    Test(T init): data{} {}
    int foo()
    {
        if constexpr(1 != N)
        {
            std::cout << "Default\n";
            return N;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Special implementation\n";
            return 0;
        }
    }
};
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/okyPcI9PdrxYGN1B)

Или вынести реализацию функции (возможно реализовать в виде type trait):

```
template<typename T, unsigned N> class
Test_foo
{
    public: static int
    foo(void)
    {
        std::cout << "Default\n";
        return N;
    }
};

template<typename T> class
Test_foo<T, 1>
{
    public: static int
    foo(void)
    {
        std::cout << "Special implementation\n";
        return 0;
    }
};

template <typename T, unsigned N>
class Test
{
private:
    T data[N];

public:
    Test(T init): data{} {}
    int foo() { return Test_foo<T, N>::foo(); }
};
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bGeqpajF2Lqvk1zp)